# Angular 7 all request to server several second as pending before reaching the server

Tags: angular, performance, lazy-loading, local, angular7

I built and finished a full angular 7 app with MySQL and PHP as database and back end language respectively.

Each sent request, even with small size response, like 100 byte, will take extra few seconds to start requesting. So at the first, as shown in the network tab, the request is `pending` then data is loaded.

[image]

A warning is always displayed at the console:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   http://dev.local/scripts/getStatistics.php with MIME type
>   application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

The api headers are like the following:

```
<?php
ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 1);
ini_set("zlib.output_compression_level", 9);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS');
header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('JWT.php');


include_once('../phpmailer/PHPMailer.php');
include_once('../phpmailer/POP3.php');
include_once('../phpmailer/SMTP.php');
include_once('../phpmailer/Exception.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Beirut');

class api {
    private $username ="root";
    ...
?>
```

The request from angular is done like the following:

```
getStatistics(){
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    return this.http.post(this.globalVar.getStatistics, { headers: headerOptions });

}
```

And the `.htaccess` when the app is working locally on offline server:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  # Specify file types in case necessary
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !echo.php
#RewriteRule .* echo.php?ua=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}&https=%{HTTPS} [L]

SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(dev.local\.com|localhost:8100|localhost:4200)$" ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ORIGIN}e env=ORIGIN
Header merge Vary Origin

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, cookie"
Header set Content-Type "application/json"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
# prevent mime based attacks
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
```

The response returned from getStatistics is an array:

```
 $res = $newApi->getStatistics($conn);
 echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

And at the angular side, where the data is displayed:

```
getStatistics(){

    this.auth.getStatistics().subscribe(
      (data)=>{

        this.result = data;
        this.totalU =  parseInt(data['uactive']) + parseInt(data['uinactive']);
        this.totalH = parseInt(data['hactive'])+parseInt(data['hinactive']);
        this.totalI = parseInt(data['iactive'])+parseInt(data['iinactive']);
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

This is an example, all server scripts are being done like that, it will add extra few seconds as pending then it will reach the server for data.

We are working on local offline server hosts and hosts are allowed on all laptops in hosts file in `system32->... folder`.

I've done few searches and found that it may be a firewall problem, and people who are reaching the server scripts waits for traffic or something.

But I don't think so as while I am developing it on my computer, it's doing the same thing.

The main problem, is on app load, where when the user open the app the first time in a day(after that it will be cached), it took about 15 seconds to open the login component. (My app is fully built using lazy loading).

Is it a local area network problem and we need to use routers with gigabit LAN ports? Or is it a code-based problem ?

I don't know if this post fit to stack overflow or it should be on other stack exchange forum. So feel free to tel me that to move it to the dedicated site.

Comment: have you enabled CORS on the server?

Comment: how to enable cors on wampserver ? @mast3rd3mon

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: if it's like the case in this link, I already allowed my host but as an IP not written: https://john-dugan.com/apache-browsersync-cross-site-requests-cors-configuration/

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I did exactly the same thing in this link but still having the same issue. https://john-dugan.com/apache-browsersync-cross-site-requests-cors-configuration/